# Как получить id текущего авторизованного пользователя в Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, ооп, laravel, api

Нужно вывести информацию о пользователе в разделе аккаунт. модель **Rhyme** и **User** связаны (**One to One**). Как можно получить id текущего авторизованного пользователя? Пытался сделать через фасад **Auth**

```
$user = Auth::user()->id;
```

возвращает **null**

Может как-то в посреднике это реализовать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет, тоже использую такой подход через фасад Auth, но у меня работает.
Перед тем, как смотреть информацию по пользователю, попробуй сделать проверку, авторизован ли пользователь?

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    /**
     * После проверки уже можешь получать любое свойство модели
     * пользователя через фасад Auth, например id
     */
    $user = Auth::user()->id;
}
```

Comment: Можешь, кстати, еще id пользователя забирать через такой метод:  $id = Auth::id(); Но предварительно тебе нужно проверять пользователя обязательно!

Comment: Забавно, всё заработало, теперь даже без проверки check, в любом случае спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто использовать:

```
Auth::id();
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не работает фасад, можно попробовать helper функцию auth(). Получиться:

```
auth()->user()->id
```